# Template tail structure raise "incomplete type in nested name specifier"

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I trying to manipulate C++14 `integer_sequence` and I'm running to an error I
don't understand. Let start with a shortcut for readability

```
template <typename Int, Int...ints>
using IS = std::integer_sequence<Int, ints...>;
```

I'm reducing a `IS` with the sum function. I've not defined it for the empty
sequence on purpose, since its the case in my actual usecase where I use
arithmetical function such as gcd and lcm:

```
template<typename ...Int> struct redsum;

template<typename Int, Int i0, Int i1, Int... ints>
struct redsum< IS<Int, i0, i1, ints...> > :
  redsum< IS<Int, i0 + i1, ints...> > { };

template<typename Int, Int i0>
struct redsum<IS<Int, i0> > : std::integral_constant< Int, i0 > { };
```

Now I'd like to define the tail (cdr in lisp):

```
template<typename Int, Int ...ints> struct tail;

template<typename Int, Int i0, Int... ints>
struct tail<Int, i0, ints...> : IS<Int, ints...> { };

template<typename Int, Int... ints>
struct tail<IS<Int, ints...> > : tail<Int, ints...> { };
```

But this doesn't work as expected:

```
// This works as expected
static_assert(redsum< IS<unsigned, 2, 5, 12, 18> >::value == 2 + 5 + 12 + 18);

// This doesn't with an incomplete type error
static_assert(redsum< tail < IS<unsigned, 2, 5, 12, 18> > >::value == 5 + 12 + 18);// EDIT
```

I don't understand where my type is incomplete in this usecase. Any
explanation or suggestion how I should write it better ?

Comment: Your intention would be clearer if you used `static_assert(5 + 12 + 18 == redsum<tail<IS<unsigned, 2, 5, 12, 18> > >::value, "")` instead of `std::cout`. I guess [@max66's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999451/2615118) is based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @Julius - I confirm: my answer was based on a misunderstanding; sorry.

Comment: @Julius - added another answer; hoping this isn't misunderstood,

Comment: @Julius:Thanks for the idea ! I'm fixing my question !

Answer (score 3):

All of your `redsum` template specializations expect the tempate parameter to be of type `std::integer_sequence`. Although class `tail` eventually inherits from `std::integer_sequence`, itself it won't match the type expected by the specializations, and so the compiler falls back to the (undefined) primary template. A classic approach in such a case is to define a nested type in the class template specialization that terminates the recursion:

```
template <typename Int, Int ...ints>
struct tail;

template <typename Int, Int i0, Int... ints>
struct tail<Int, i0, ints...> { using type = IS<Int, ints...>; };
//                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^

template <typename Int, Int... ints>
struct tail<IS<Int, ints...>> : tail<Int, ints...> {};
```

Then access the nested type to get the result of this transformation:

```
 redsum< tail < IS<unsigned, 2, 5, 12, 18> >::type >::value
 //                                         ~~~~~^
```

Comment: OK ! I think I more or less understand the problem. I've seen the classical approach, but it seemed to me unecessarily complicated. Now I know why. Do you have any reference explaining how this match is performed and why in my case it doesn't ?

Answer (score 2):

Piotr (+1) [explained correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999217/2615118) why you get an error.

Anyway, if you want call `tail` only with an `std::integer_sequence`

```
tail<IS<long, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L>>
```

and not directly with a list

```
tail<long, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L>
```

you can impose that `tail` receive only a typename, and not the following list of integers

```
template <typename>
struct tail;
```

and defining the wanted type as inner `type` (as suggested by Piotr), you can implement it with a single specialization

```
template <typename Int, Int i0, Int... ints>
struct tail<IS<Int, i0, ints...>>
 { using type = IS<Int, ints...>; };
```

But I suggest to be more generic and not depend from `std::integer_sequence` and to implement `tail` to work with a generic container

```
template <template <typename T, T...> class C,
          typename Int, Int i0, Int... ints>
struct tail<C<Int, i0, ints...>>
 { using type = C<Int, ints...>; };
```

so if you define a container as

```
template <typename T, T...>
struct myList
 { };
```

it's satisfied the following `static_assert()`

```
static_assert( std::is_same<tail<myList<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>>::type,
                            myList<int, 3, 5, 7>>{}, "!");
```

Same suggestion for `redsum`; you can define it as receiving a single type

```
template <typename>
struct redsum;
```

and generalize it to support a generic container (maintained a `value` based on `std::ingeger_constant`)

```
template <template <typename T, T...> class C, 
          typename Int, Int i0, Int i1, Int... ints>
struct redsum< C<Int, i0, i1, ints...> > :
  redsum< C<Int, i0 + i1, ints...> >
 { };

template <template <typename T, T...> class C, typename Int, Int i0>
struct redsum<C<Int, i0> > : std::integral_constant< Int, i0 >
 { using type = C<Int, i0>; };
```

so the following `static_assert()` are satisfied

```
static_assert( std::is_same<redsum<myList<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>>::type,
                            myList<int, 17>>{}, "!" );

static_assert( redsum<myList<int, 2, 3, 5, 7>>::value == 17, "!" );
```

Finally... your tagged this question as C++14 but I want to show you how much simpler can be your `redsum` with C++17

```
template <typename>
struct redsum;

template <template <typename T, T...> class C, typename Int, Int... ints>
struct redsum< C<Int, ints...> >
   : std::integral_constant<Int, (ints + ...)>
 { using type = C<Int, (ints + ...)>; };
```

Comment: +1. ... and for an explanation why the approach in the question failed see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999217/2615118).

Comment: @Julius - you're right: the Piotr's answer deserve a clearer mention for the point of the original failure. Answer modified.